# To Read the filepath and open that file using powershell

Tags: powershell

I have a file 'one.txt' that contains one line of file path of another file like below.

```
\\Myfilepath1\filepath\two.csv
```

First, I need to open the file 'one.txt' and access the above the file path and then open the file whichever present in that file path to do some process. In this case it is 'two.csv'.
I'm aware that we need to do something with the below code, but I'm unclear as how to completely construct it.

```
$file = Get-ChildItem  -LiteralPath
$stream = $file.OpenRead()
...
$stream.Close()
```

Could you please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple way to do it:

```
$FilePath = Get-Content -Path "C:\temp\path.txt"
.$FilePath
```

Comment: In my case, is this correct one? $FilePath = Get-Content -Path "C:\temp\one.txt" .$FilePath Will it open my 'two'csv' file that is present as filepath in the file 'one.txt'

Comment: You only need to change the filepath which you read with get content.